# What exactly were the controller roles in the Apollo go/no-go calls?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, terminology, procedure, launch-sequence

In the Apollo era, whenever there was a significant event about to occur, the flight director (I can recall the voice of Gene Kranz) would do a sort of go/no-go "roll call". He would call off names like "fido", "gido"(?), etc. (obviously shortened from a more meaningful title), to which someone would respond with a "go" (don't ever recall hearing a "no go"). Views of the controller room showed perhaps dozens of people; the director called off maybe 7 names.

What were the short names short for (what was the full title and scope of responsibility), and how was a room full of controllers organized so that only a short call-off list properly represented an over-all "go"/"no-go" status?

Comment: The short list is a result of the fact that the front room controllers are actually the tip of a larger group of back room controllers as well.  So, for example, the flight dynamics officer has a whole cadre of controllers that he communicates with as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That "GIDO" would probably be "GUIDO" (Guidance Officer). Here's some of the most common Apollo program [flight controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller) station call signs (from linked to Wikipedia page):

> - [Common flight control positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Common_flight_control_positions)
>
>   - [Flight Director (FLIGHT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Flight_Director_.28FLIGHT.29)
>   - [Mission Operations Directorate (MOD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Mission_Operations_Directorate_.28MOD.29)
>   - [Capsule Communicator (CAPCOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Capsule_Communicator_.28CAPCOM.29)
>   - [Flight Surgeon (SURGEON)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Flight_Surgeon_.28SURGEON.29)
>   - [Public Affairs Officer (PAO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Public_Affairs_Officer_.28PAO.29)
> - [Apollo flight control positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Apollo_flight_control_positions)
>
>   - [Booster Systems Engineer (BOOSTER)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Booster_Systems_Engineer_.28BOOSTER.29)
>   - [Control Officer (CONTROL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Control_Officer_.28CONTROL.29)
>   - [Electrical, Environmental and Consumables Manager (EECOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Electrical.2C_Environmental_and_Consumables_Manager_.28EECOM.29)
>   - [Flight Activities Officer (FAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Flight_Activities_Officer_.28FAO.29))
>   - [Flight Dynamics Officer (FDO or FIDO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Flight_Dynamics_Officer_.28FDO_or_FIDO.29)
>   - [Guidance Officer (GUIDANCE or GUIDO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Guidance_Officer_.28GUIDANCE_or_GUIDO.29)
>   - [Guidance, Navigation, and Controls Systems Engineer (GNC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Guidance.2C_Navigation.2C_and_Controls_Systems_Engineer_.28GNC.29)
>   - [Instrumentation and Communications Officer (INCO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Instrumentation_and_Communications_Officer_.28INCO.29)
>   - [Network (NETWORK)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Network_.28NETWORK.29)
>   - [Organization and Procedures Officer (O&P)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Organization_and_Procedures_Officer_.28O.26P.29)
>   - [Retrofire Officer (RETRO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Retrofire_Officer_.28RETRO.29)
>   - [Telemetry, Electrical, EVA Mobility Unit Officer (TELMU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_controller#Telemetry.2C_Electrical.2C_EVA_Mobility_Unit_Officer_.28TELMU.29)

Please see the links for stations' descriptions. Also see [Wikipedia on Launch status check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launch_status_check#Apollo_missions) (maybe it would be a better source for the quote above... *shrug*).

Answer (score 0):

This article explains every station in mission command.

https://arstechnica.com/science/2012/10/apollo-flight-controller-101-every-console-explained/

Comment: As this stands it is a link-only answer. Answers on stack-exchange should at least attempt to paraphrase what is in the link, in-case the link itself goes dead. It should be removed, or you should add 1-2 block quotes from the source :). Not an attack on the content or on you, just the rules!

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Please [edit] the essential parts into your text.